# PHP DocDocument, in saveXML() function change &quot; by "

Tags: php, xml, quotes

I try to use DOMDocument library, but i need the original XML text without further changes because is a signed xml with a digital certificate (XMLSecurityKey openssl).

The simples steps, loadxml and savexml change the original text.

My code is:

```
$PROCESSED_TEXT = "<node><child>product &amp; &apos; &gt; &lt; &quot;</child></node>";

$obj = new DOMDocument();  
$obj->formatOutput = false; // (needed)
$obj->preserveWhiteSpace = true; // (needed)
$obj->encoding = 'ISO-8859-1'; // (needed)

$obj->loadXML($PROCESSED_TEXT);

$strXMLFinal = $obj->saveXML();

echo $strXMLFinal;
```

OUTPUT:

```
<node><child>producto &amp; ' &gt; &lt; "</child></node>
```

I need the same:

```
<node><child>product &amp; &apos; &gt; &lt; &quot;</child></node>
```

I tried without success with:

```
$obj->xmlStandalone = true;
$obj->substituteEntities = false;
$obj->resolveExternals = false;
$obj->strictErrorChecking = false;
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730933/is-there-a-way-to-keep-entities-intact-while-parsing-html-with-domdocument ? Silly, but replace entities to something else, return them back after all work is done )

Answer (score 1):

Your input and output are exactly the same as far as the DOM is concerned. That your signed input contains `&apos;` and `&quot;` indicates that the signing procedure used is incorrect. Prior to signing the XML should be [canonicalized](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n) as there can be many equally valid serializations that would otherwise break an XML signature.

---

[W3C Canonical XML Recommendation, Section 2.3](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-c14n#ProcessingModel):

> **Text Nodes-** the string value, except all ampersands are replaced by `&amp;`, all open angle brackets (<) are replaced by `&lt;`, all closing angle brackets (>) are replaced by `&gt;`, and all #xD characters are replaced by `&#xD;`.

---

Specifically left out are `'` and `"` being represented as `&apos;` and `&quot;`.

The only place in canonicalized XML you should find `&quot;` is within an attribute value and nowhere should you find `&apos;`.

Also note that instead of `$obj->saveXML()` you can use `$obj->C14N()` to ensure that your output is in the canonical form and as such will match appropriately signed input.

---

If you are unable to receive correct input your only option is manipulating the XML string after serialization. Exactly how to do it - whether pre-processing to mark special characters and post-processing to replace them; or wholesale replacement of part of your output with the original input string - largely depends on what you're doing with all of this in the first place.